# Solving a non-separable linear partial differential equation? (polar coordinates)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is it possible to solve a non-separable linear partial differential equation in polar coordinates? What kind of method would I need to use?

In particular, the equation I want to solve is this one:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}=-\vec{a}\cdot\nabla f,
$$
where $f=f(r,\theta)$ and $\vec{a}=\vec{a}(r,\theta)$.

Comment: That looks like a linear equation, doesn't it? And $(r,\theta)$ look like polar coordinates, not spherical. And I suppose you mean $f=f(r,\theta,t)$? Is $\vec{a}$ some particular function that you know explicitly, or do you seek a general answer in terms of $\vec{a}$? And by $\nabla f$ here, do you mean the expression for the gradient in polar coordinates?

Comment: Oh actually, yes it is linear. Technically it is in spherical coordinates but all the quantities are constant in the $\phi$ direction. So yeah, I suppose polar coordinates are equivalent here, although they are not for some other part of the problem I am working on. We know $\vec{a}$ explicitly, but we would still like a general answer in terms of it. And yes, $\nabla$ is the gradient in polar coordinates.

Something I completely forgot: the solution is supposed to be a wave. Maybe I can try as an ansatz a spherical wave. I'll try that.

Comment: If you assume $f = e^{i \omega t} g$ then you now have a first order equation in $g$ that can be solved via method of characteristics.

Comment: Ok great, I will try that. Thanks!